# Should I host services on different ports for optimal load balance?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I am working on a distributed application where I'll be hosting multiple WCF services on a server. I'll be hosting these services in IIS.

Assuming that there is only one physical server machine, will there be any impact on performance if I host multiple webservice on a same port?

Simply said, I need to find which of the following method is better, or both are same performance wise.

1. Different services on same port

   - localhost:1066/MathsService
   - localhost:1066/PhysicsService
   - localhost:1066/ChemistryService
2. Different services on different ports

   - localhost:1066/MathsService
   - localhost:1067/PhysicsService
   - localhost:1068/ChemistryService

I tried to find the information on internet but I didn't manage to find any useful material. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really think it will make any significant difference? Hint - it does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosting multiple WCF services on single TCP port in one windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662231/hosting-multiple-wcf-services-on-single-tcp-port-in-one-windows-service)

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662231/hosting-multiple-wcf-services-on-single-tcp-port-in-one-windows-service
Your question is a subset of this question. And TomTom is right, there   is no perf hit

Comment: @TomTom: Thanks, I was thinking the same.